# Python unstack value error: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stack, pivot

I'm trying to unstack a df:

```
Site   Month   Class   Data
A      11      Bike    20
A      11      Car     200
A      12      Bike    30
A      12      Car     300
B      11      Bike    40
B      11      Car     400
B      12      Bike    50
B      12      Car     500
```

Below is the dataframe I want:

```
Site   Month   Bike   Car   
A      11      20     200
A      12      30     300
B      11      40     400
B      12      50     500
```

When I tried df.set_index(['Site','Month']).unstack(), it reported "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape" because after setting index in df, first and second row would have same index A/11.

It there another way I can get the desired result? You can use the code below to generate df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Site': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4:'B', 5:'B', 6:'B', 7:'B'},
    'Month': {0: 11, 1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 12, 4:11, 5:11, 6:12, 7:12},
    'Class': {0: 'Bike', 1: 'Car', 2: 'Bike', 3: 'Car', 4: 'Bike', 5: 'Car', 6: 'Bike', 7: 'Car',},
    'Data': {0: 20, 1: 200, 2: 30, 3: 300, 4:40, 5:400, 6:50, 7:500}})
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option would be using [**`Dataframe.pivot`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html) method such as

```py
pvt = df.pivot(index=['Site','Month'], columns="Class", values="Data")
print(pvt)

Class       Bike  Car
Site Month           
A    11       20  200
     12       30  300
B    11       40  400
     12       50  500
```

where the values of the argument for the **columns** parameter(**Class**) are distinctly pivoted to be new column names.

PS. it's possible to replace **`df.pivot`** with [**`df.pivot_table`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) which also have a richer set of parameters such as **aggfunc** if needed to be used at another time.